# Pass Variables to Partial in Controller

Tags: zend-framework, partial

I am attempting to create a body variable for an email I want to send in Zend. I am able to load the partial and pass it to my Model where it is then packaged and sent on its way. The issue I am having is that I want to pass $buyer into the partial in order to use the post information to populate the email.

$buyer contains all my post data. So I have the name, address, phone number, and other information in side that variable. $body2 is just a simple HTML script that I want to be able to populate with information from $buyer before emailing it.

```
// Get the Post Data
$buyer = $request->getPost();
// Creates the body for the email with the users information
$body2  = $this->view->partial('partials/enterpriseContact.phtml');
```

I tried doing -

```
$body2 = $this->view->partial('partials/enterpriseContact.phtml', $buyer);
```

But that did not work. I am working inside the controller if that makes a difference. The complete code block looks thus -

```
// Get the Post Data
$buyer = $request->getPost();
// Create the body variable by loading the partial for the post card.
$body   = $this->view->partial('partials/postcardEmail/eform1stpostcard.htm');
// Creates the body for the business email with the users information
$body2  = $this->view->partial('partials/enterpriseContact.phtml');
// New Model For Mail Client
$mailUs = new Model_MailUs(); // Instantiate the model to handle Emails
// Use that model to send the email, requires variables, who to send to, and body
$mailUs->sendMail($request->getPost(),  'guest',    $body);  // Sends an email to the user
$mailUs->sendMail($request->getPost(),  'link',  $body2); // Sends an email to us
```

How do I put variables inside a partial from the controller in Zend?

Comment: `$this->view->partial('partials/enterpriseContact.phtml', $buyer);` is correct. Did you do any debugging to see whether `$buyer` was indeed an array, or to test inside the partial whether it received one of the variables? Can you add an example of how you are accessing the variables within the partial?

Comment: I was missing the array('buyer' => $buyer) in the partial. I updated below.

Comment: Depending on how you are accessing the data within the partial, this shouldn't be necessary, since $buyer is already an array. So if you have a field called 'name' in your post data then it would be accessed with `$this->name` in your partial. If you pass `$buyer` in nested in an array then it would be `$this->buyer['name']`.

Comment: I didn't even try to print out $this->firstName. I didn't think of that. You are probably correct! I was trying to access it using buyer['name']. Ugh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, you should be able to use:

```
// in controller or do this all the way back at bootstrap
$this->view->partial()->setObjectKey('mykey');

// in controller
$renderedContent = $this->view->partial('path/to/partial.phtml', $someData);
```

Then in the partial itself:

```
<?php 
$someData = $this->mykey
// now use $someData as you like
?>
```

But, frankly, I usually end up doing the more verbose thing:

```
// In controller
$renderedContent = $this->view->partial('path/to/partial.phtml', array(
    'mykey' => 'myval',
));
```

Then in the partial:

```
<?php echo $this->mykey ?>
```

Comment: I am voting this the answer because it is a better answer than mine; and it explains both ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$body2  = $this->view->partial('partials/enterpriseContact.phtml', array('buyer' => $buyer));
```

You have to use the word array and then set the variable collection into the partial as above.
I was then able to access the variables by typing echo $this->buyer in my partial.